# Unable to match entire regex

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I would like to know whether or not a certain string has a regex.

I wrote the code below which in order to match strings similar to the following:

**"A|3|a3\n"**

However the code below gets an array of matches. I do not want that as I want to simply understand whether or not my response string matches the criteria given by the regex. Any suggestion on how to do so?

```
    NSString * response = "A|3|a3\n";
    NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [ response length]);
    NSString *pattern = @"[ABC]\|[0-9]\|[a][0-9]$";
    NSError  *error = nil;

    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:response options:0 range: searchedRange];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches){
    NSString* matchText = [response substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", matchText);
}
```

Comment: FYI, `[a]` is the same as `a`.

Comment: `@"[ABC]\\|[0-9]\\|[a][0-9]$"` XCode should throw a warning because of `\|`. So you have to use `\\` instead.

Comment: @Larme Maybe you should put this as an answer. I wanted to but I saw you were faster.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode should throw an warning:

```
Warning: Unknown escape sequence '\|'
```

for this line:

```
NSString *pattern = @"[ABC]\|[0-9]\|[a][0-9]$";
```

"\" escape indeed the next character (to some special signification, like the classical "\n"), but "\|" is a unknown escape sequence for a normal string. So you have to "double it":

```
NSString *pattern = @"[ABC]\\|[0-9]\\|[a][0-9]$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a kind of an `IsMatch()` function. Here is an example:

```
NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:response options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:searchedRange];

BOOL isFound = NO;
// Did we find a matching range
if (matchRange.location != NSNotFound)
    isFound = YES;
```

Comment: I am looking for a function (built in?) that check if a string conforms to the entire regex.